# Using mysql i need to add html code to fields with links in it

Tags: mysql

I have a table conversation with a column messages that can have a url like:

```
https://exampleweb1.com
```

or

```
enter in: http://exampleweb2.com
```

and i need to change them into:

```
<a href="https://exampleweb1.com" target="_blank">Link to web</a>

enter in: <a href="https://exampleweb2.com" target="_blank">Link to web</a>
```

how can i do it using only mysql?
I don't know what the links are, they are messages people send to each other and i need to concat them with the a href so i can display it in a web browser.
Thanks

Comment: I think you are going to need to show us the Schema for this table, some real example data from the table and an example of what you actually want to convert that data to

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE() will solve.

Comment: I will investigate about regexp_replace(), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
UPDATE conversation SET message=
concat(
    substring_index(message,'http',1), 
    '<a href="http',
    substring_index(substring_index(message,'http',-1), ' ',1),
    '" target="_blank">Link to web</a>',
    SUBSTRING(substring_index(message,'http',-1), LOCATE(" ", substring_index(message,'http',-1)), 1024)
) WHERE message LIKE '%http%'
```